# Display a list of user's posts in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I have a rails app where users post reviews of albums. The reviews that are posted are called "pins" and are uploaded with a  release date, album title, artist name, album cover image, and rank for the year. (as in my #1 favorite album of the year) The pins belong users and the users have many pins. What I want to do is create a new page for 2013 that displays each user, then lists a descending ordered list of the album image, title, artist as their top ten list for the year. Something like:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
<%= link_to (image_tag user.image(:small)), user %> <%= user.name %>
<ol>   
  <li><%= @pin.album %> - <% @pin.artist%></li>     
    </ol>   
<% end %>
```

I need to limit the pins to only :date => "2013" and I need to list them in descending order.

I'm having trouble figuring out the controller and view. Here is my page controller so far:

```
def tens2013
  @users = User.all
  @pin = Pin.where(:date => "2013")
end
```

How should I set my controller to be able to call <%= @pin.user.album %> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it, your models should be set up like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pins
end

class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :album
end

class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pins
end
```

`Pin` should have `user_id` and `album_id` to achieve this.

Then in the controller, you can eager load all users and their pins, with each pin's respective album, like this:

```
@users = User.includes(:pins => :album)
```

Or to limit to a certain year, do:

```
@users = User.includes(:pins => :album).where('pins.date>=?','2013-01-01').references(:pins)
```

Now you can iterate through the users in your view, and through each user's pins, and each pin's album.

You don't need to use `@pin` for each user's pin. Make the necessary changes in your view, and iterate through them using this style:

```
@users.each do |user|
  # do something 
  user.pins.each do |pin|
    # Now you have "pin" and you can use it:
    # pin.album...
    # pin.artist...
  end
end
```

Comment: thank you so much for putting this effort into answering. There is a pin model and a user model. album is only an attribute of pin. I think the way you describe above, album is being treated like its own model. Correct?

Comment: Correct. Perhaps that's because I didn't understand your model? Album seems more like an entity of its own and pin a kind of review of an album, if I get you right, no?

Comment: Sorry, the pin is the nickname of the entire post. A user adds a "pin" which has attributes: image (the album art), album (the title), artist  (the artist's name), date (release year), rank (favorite rank of the year, like #1) I can list the users and their attributes, and how many pins they have, but I'm trying to also list the attributes of those pins. I don't have the ability to chat otherwise I would. It would make this easier.

Comment: Got you. I updated the answer bro. You're using a class variable (@) when there's no need to.

Comment: That's it! I don't need to make Pin belongs_to :album, but I didn't understand that I needed to nest the user.pins.each inside of the users.each. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

1. To call `@pin.user.album`, you need to define the dependency first at the model level. So in the `Pin` model, you should have `belongs_to :users` and in the `User` model, you should include `has_many :pins`. Now this will assume that in the `Pin` model, there is a field called `user_id`, which will be the foreign key. Also use `:include` in the queries when you are going to access dependent classes like this. It avoids the N+1 query problem. eg:

   ```
   @pin = Pin.includes(:users).where("date >= ?","2013-01-01")
   ```
2. To limit responses to only the year 2013, you may want to search your query likewise:

   ```
   @pin = Pin.where("date >= ?","2013-01-01")
   ```

Comment: Thanks for responding. Yes I have pin belongs_to :users and users has_many :pins. Pin has the user_id. My site works great for what i use it for currently. I'm running into trouble creating the 2013 page in specific. using your advice above, when I call @pin.user.album I get undefined method `user' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007f964f893c20>

Comment: Change belongs_to :users to belongs_to :user (in sigular). That should work.

Comment: I'm sorry, my typo. I have it as belongs_to :user

Comment: as mjnissim mentioned, belongs_to :user should fix the problem. Is it still happening ?

Comment: Yes, still happening. I get: undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass

Comment: My friend Tony, that is something else completely. Make sure you're not calling "user" on some "nil" object. In other words, make sure you're working with an object. Only God creates Ex nihilo...

Comment: I'm calling <%= @pin.user.album %>. Is there some way to find what is causing it?

Comment: It could be it found no pins at all, so it's returning this error. It's saying, "@pin" is nil, and nil doesn't have the method "user".

Comment: It also seems to me that "album" should not belong to user, so as to say "user.album", but that the pin should belong to the album.

Comment: @mjnissim Ok, right. album belongs to pin. If I just call pin.album I get undefined method album for nil:NilClass